# Which target to build after making a change to a system service in AOSP?

Tags: android, android-source, android-build

I am trying to verify a small change I have made in the Activity Manager service (mostly logs that I have added). I am using the android-8.1.0_r42 aosp version and using its emulator.

- I am using an eng build.
- I have done a module makes (`mm`) and then, `make services` which generated the services.jar, services.odex, etc. However, I am unable to remount the system partition on the emulator (command used: `mount -o rw, remount /system`, on the ADB shell, but doing a push(adb push) of any of the generated services binary is failing due to reading the only partition).
- So I regenerated the system.img by doing a - `make snod`. However, my changes are not consumed in the emulator instance I launched after generating the new system.img.

Is there a way I can verify my changes without doing a top-level full build, which takes quite a long?

Comment: Make sure to flash the system.img after generating it.

Comment: I am running this on the emulator. So after generating the system.img with make snod, I launch the emulator again. That should consume the changes, ryt ?

Answer (score -1):

It could be the case that [DM-verity](https://source.android.com/security/verifiedboot/dm-verity) is enabled and prevents you from writing to the system partition after remounting.
Assuming you are working with a userdebug version, try the following:

- adb root
- adb disable-verity
- adb reboot
- adb root
- adb remount

Now you should be able to push your files to the remounted partition without getting the read-only error.

Comment: It is an eng build and does not have verity enabled.